# Good Software Engineering Concepts: Messed Up Database vs Everything in one

Tags: sql, database

First of all, I will explain the situation. Please read it carefully.

I am creating an java phonebook software. I created a database with fields Name, address, mobile1, mobile2, landPh1, landPh2, etc. After 90% completed, I decided to expand it functionalties. As a result of that, I started working with VCards, now that program can read VCards and add them to the DB. Then I decided to write VCards using the data stored in the database. Here, problem occurs!!

VCards don't have field called "Name", as I have in my software. Instead of that, they have "First Name", "Last Name" and "Middle Name". VCards don't have "Address" as I have in my software too. They have "country", "city" and "street address". Now, how can I get these SEPARATE details???? I can get only the name, not the first, last etc. I can get only the address, not the country, city, etc. Now what can I do?????? Below are my suggestions

1. get the complete name. Set it to VCards "first name" field. You will have the complete name there. For address, add the complete address to VCard's "Street Address" field.
2. Edit the database, alter it and add the missing fields. But then, the DB will look like this

firstName, Address, mobile1, mobile2, landPh1, landPh2, middleName, lastName, country, city

pretty messy, isn't it?

I am unable to drop the table because lot of stuff has been created based on current format!! Changing it will take lot of time!!

I don't know whether above suggestions are OK with good software engineering concepts. If you have a better way, I am glad to hear that too. Please help!!

Comment: You need a data access layer.

Comment: A SQL database does not have fields. It has tables with columns (relations).

Comment: i will suggest denormalizing the table, have a table Person(id, first name, middle name, last name), Address(id,person_id,....<rest of the fields>), Phone_details(person_id, no, type). I know this will take a lot of time and work, but it will make your app more extensible

Comment: Who cares how it looks in the database? No-one displays data exactly as it is returned from the database. You _select_ what you want in the order you want it and manipulate it as you desire. Add the fields you should have added at the beginning. Have a good attempt at splitting out county and city from address and be prepared to be cleaning it up for the next year and remember what you did wrong for the next time.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, a DAL won't help with the fact that county and city are concatenated together and probably not with splitting out names into multiple components. There are just too many variables.

Comment: Just save the zip code. The city and state are derived anyway.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Special thanks goes to Ankur and Ben. As Ben said, I will follow the normalization good work from my next project onwards, if I do now, it will be a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a number of mistakes in your original database design.  You should correct those mistakes at the earliest possible time as the longer you maintain the system with the design flaws the more difficult it will be to correct them later.

In short you need to:

1. Ensure that each column contains one and only one piece of information.  That means separate columns for the parts of the name, separate columns for the parts of the address, etc.
2. You need to ensure that you are not storing multiple instances of the same item in a single record.  That means creating a separate table for the phone numbers.  Most likely this table will have three columns, an ID to point back to the contact person, a column for the phone number, and a description.

You will never be able to accurately "decode" 100% of the possible addresses and names.

You can read more about the rules for good database design by googling `database normalization`.

Don't worry about the order of the columns in a table, or the records in the table.  SQL does not contain a concept of default ordering, instead you order the columns and records as you want on retrieval.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I analyzed the answer, and found I am unable to do this for the current project, because it will affect everything and lot of inner joins will occur (u knw, more than 20!!), so I am going with the "Messed up DB". However, I understand this is the best way. From now onwards, I will make sure to do all these normalization stuff as much as possible, and make a good design. Thank you! +1 from me :)

Comment: While changing a database design after the fact means you will have to do a good deal of work, you can sometimes eliminate some of the work by using VIEWs to "recreate" your tables in the database engine, meaning that you don't have to rewrite your SELECTs (but you're still on the hook for INSERTs and UPDATEs).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I would:

- don't worry too much about the physical ordering of columns in the db. New columns are usually appended at the end of production databases without recreation of the tables.

  - keep your data normalized, i.e. don't combine all your name and address fields into one column, as it is cumbersome to split these later.
  - you might consider normalizing your address and vcf card data into separate tables which are 1:N with your person / contacts table. This will allow for multiple vcard and addresses per person.